# Value type confusion

Tags: java, swift, class, value-type

My first question on StackOverflow :)

I started to learn Swift in XCode a few days ago and I'm having some trouble understanding the value type in Swift. Since I'm quite familiar with Java, I'm just going to explain my question in Java. Here's what I want to write in Swift.

```
class Node {
    public int value; 
    public List<Integer> children;
    public Node parent;

    public Node() {
        value = 0;
        children = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    }

    public Node bestChild() {
        Node result = new Node();
        for (child : this.children) {
            if (child.value > result.value)
                result = child;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

For the sake of this question, let's not talk about private, public, or generic here. Just keep it simple!
Here's my try in Swift.

```
public class Node {
    var value: Int
    var children: NSSet
    var parent: Node?

    public init() {
        self.value = 0
        children = NSSet()
    }

    public func bestChild() -> Node {
        var result = Node()
        for child in children {
            if (child.value > result.value) {      //error
                result = child                     //error
            }
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

Both the condition for the if statement and the line inside have errors. XCode suggested casting the variables but still it didn't solve the errors.

```
if ((child as AnyObject).value > result.value) {
    result = child as! Node
}
```

Since Java is the only language I know, if someone could explain it in term of Java I would greatly appreciate it. If not, please keep it simple so I can wrap my head around it :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you using `NSSet`? Is `[Int]` not suitable? [Collection types in Swift 3](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-ID105)

Comment: All you need to do is change `NSSet` to `Set<Int>` Your design is probably questionable, but if you're just learning don't worry about that part of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

welcome to Stack Overflow and Swift programming!

### Improvements to the Java code

Firstly, I suggest some changes to the Java code.

1. Use static initializers where possible. After doing this, you don't even need an explicit constructor.
2. Your `children` variable is type `List<Integer>`, but I suspect you meant it to be `List<Node>`.
3. Don't create a new `Node` just for comparison's sake. With this approach, if `bestChild()` returns a `Node` with a value of 0, it can't be known if that's because the children list was empty, of if there really was a `Node` with value 0 that was the highest value. I would use the stream API, though you could manually implement such functionality.

Here is the end result:

```
class Node {
    public int value;
    public List<Node> children = new ArrayList<>();
    public Node parent; // Unused?

    public Node bestChild() {
        // Modern, easy approach:
        return children
               .stream()
               .max((x, y) -> Integer.compare(x.value, y.value))
               .get();

        // Old, classic Java approach:
        /*
        int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        Node maxNode = null;

        for (Node child : this.children) {
            if (max < child.value) {
                max = child.value;
                maxNode = child;
             }
        }

        return maxNode; */
    }
}
```

### The Swift equivalent

Here's how I would write this in Swift. Feel free to ask follow up questions

```
class Node {
    let value = 0
    let children = [Node]()
    weak var parent: Node? // Unused?

    func bestChild() -> Node? {
        return children.max(by: { $0.value < $1.value })
    }
}
```

### The Swift equivalent of the antiquated Java apporach

Here's the Swift implementation of the antiquated Java approach to the `bestChild` method. This is just for comparison's sake. *DON'T DO THIS!*

```
func bestChild() -> Node? {
    var max = Int.min
    var maxNode: Node?

    for child in children {
        if max < child.value {
            max = child.value
            maxNode = child
        }
    }

    return maxNode
}
```

### To address the issues in your solution attempt:

`NSSet` is to `Swift`, as `HashSet` (without the generic type parameter, *not* `HashSet<T>`) is to Java. It's a datatype from the `Foundation` library, that was invented for Objective-C. You shouldn't be using it in Swift in 99.999% of cases. `NSSet` acts as a set of `AnyObject`. In order to be able to call `.value` on an object from the set, you need to first manually cast the object to `Node`.

The solution to all that is to instead use `Set<Int>`, which is Swift's native `Set` data structure. Though this raises the question, why are you using a Set in the swift solution, but an array in the Java solution?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! That piece of code isn't the whole class, so parent is not unused, and actually, I have multiple constructors so I didn't initialize the class variable. That being said, how do you create a second "constructor" in Swift. Or is it even possible? And please tell me a little bit more about (by: { $0.value < $1.value }), that would be very helpful. I didn't expect an answer that is this detailed. So again, thanks a lot!

Comment: You can have as many initializers in a type as you'd like, and you can even add initializers to Classes that aren't your own. [They're covered here.](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html)

Comment: Are you familiar with lambda expressions in Java? Swift's equivalent is called a closure, and they're significantly better designed and easier to use. `{ $0.value < $1.value }` is a closure that takes two arguments (both inferred to be of type `Node`) and returns a `Bool` (inferred from the definition of `<`), which defines the comparison order by which the `min` is to be found. [You can read about them here.](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html)